# How to filter products in cart page using category id?

Tags: magento, filter, shopping-cart, categories, product

I need to filter the products in cart page by using category id. In cart page i am using $this->getItems(). I don't know how to filter. If you have any ideas, please help me.

Answer (score 0):

For this you have to edit the product collection which is coming in cart controller then
you can filter the cart product by using category id like this

**`$this->addFilter('category_id',array('1,2,3'));`**
or 
**`$this->addAttributeToFilter('category_id',array('1,2,3'));`**
or 
**`$this->addFieldToFilter('category_id',array('1,2,3'));`**

Try this and reply me

Comment: Sorry Mohit Verma, Its not working. if you any other idea about this, please give your suggestions.